# riemann stieltjes integrablity

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be riemann stieltjes integrable w.r.t $a$;
let $g$ be a continious linear functional on $\mathscr{C}[a,b]$.
Then $g(f)= \int_{a}^{b} f da$.
Is it riesz thorem?
Can anyone refer any link to the proof of the theorem?
Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks in advance.[image]
Can anyone please help me in proving the theorem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody is going to answer this with the current formatting. I recommend you retype this with Latex.

Comment: For formatting tips, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yeah, OP, you're probably looking for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

Comment: Or perhaps you want the [original version proven by Riesz.](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/riesz-proves-riesz-representation-theorem)

Comment: Please do look through the formatting guide shared above. Also, it seems like inconsistent notation you're using.. the lower integral bound is $a$ and the variable you are integrating over is also $a$? $\int_a^b f \, da$?

Comment: From what you wrote, it is not the statement of Riesz theorem. Guess you misstated what you were after. By the way, the statement is false; it says that every linear functional is constant...

Comment: Riesz had many theorems.I did not meant one of the famous ones.